# smoothing plot edges

Tags: plotting

I have a data list as `mydata`:

```
{{0., 0., 1.41421}, {0., 0.1, 1.34443}, {0., 0.2, 1.27671}, {0.,    0.3, 
1.2114}, {0., 0.4, 1.14891}, {0., 0.5, 1.08972}, {0., 0.6, 
1.03441}, {0., 0.7, 0.983616}, {0., 0.8, 0.938083}, {0., 0.9, 
0.89861}, {0., 1., 0.866025}, {0., 1.1, 0.84113}, {0., 1.2, 
 0.824621}, {0., 1.3, 0.817007}, {0., 1.4, 0.818535}, {0., 1.5, 
0.829156}, {0., 1.6, 0.848528}, {0., 1.7, 0.876071}, {0., 1.8, 
0.911043}, {0., 1.9, 0.952628}, {0., 2., 1.}, {0.1, 0., 
0.00703606}, {0.1, 0.1, 0.00370881}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.0845224}, {0.1, 
 0.3, 0.0041416}, {0.1, 0.4, 0.00877084}, {0.1, 0.5, 
  0.0139434}, {0.1, 0.6, 0.0197103}, {0.1, 0.7, 0.0261095}, {0.1, 0.8,
 0.0331517}, {0.1, 0.9, 0.0408017}, {0.1, 1., 0.035519}, {0.1, 1.1, 
 0.0287572}, {0.1, 1.2, 0.0224126}, {0.1, 1.3, 0.0166955}, {0.1, 1.4,
 0.0117739}, {0.1, 1.5, 0.00774973}, {0.1, 1.6, 0.00464883}, {0.1, 
 1.7, 0.00242825}, {0.1, 1.8, 0.000994854}, {0.1, 1.9, 
 0.000228041}, {0.1, 2., 0.1}, {0.2, 0., 0.0277401}, {0.2, 0.1, 
 0.0219557}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.0154776}, {0.2, 0.3, 0.00819939}, {0.2, 
 0.4, 0.134144}, {0.2, 0.5, 0.00925524}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.0197103}, {0.2,
  0.7, 0.0315091}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.0447775}, {0.2, 0.9, 
 0.0595936}, {0.2, 1., 0.0607365}, {0.2, 1.1, 0.0488353}, {0.2, 1.2, 
 0.0378543}, {0.2, 1.3, 0.028094}, {0.2, 1.4, 0.0197763}, {0.2, 1.5, 
 0.0130176}, {0.2, 1.6, 0.00782267}, {0.2, 1.7, 0.00409927}, {0.2, 
 1.8, 0.00168684}, {0.2, 1.9, 0.00038868}, {0.2, 2., 0.2}, {0.3, 0., 
  0.0610078}, {0.3, 0.1, 0.0536451}, {0.3, 0.2, 0.0453824}, {0.3, 0.3,
  0.0360728}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.0255437}, {0.3, 0.5, 0.0135953}, {0.3, 
 0.6, 0.14825}, {0.3, 0.7, 0.0154939}, {0.3, 0.8, 0.0331517}, {0.3, 
 0.9, 0.0532305}, {0.3, 1., 0.0759413}, {0.3, 1.1, 0.0633931}, {0.3, 
 1.2, 0.0489856}, {0.3, 1.3, 0.0362869}, {0.3, 1.4, 0.0255279}, {0.3,
 1.5, 0.0168138}, {0.3, 1.6, 0.0101212}, {0.3, 1.7, 
 0.00531784}, {0.3, 1.8, 0.00219572}, {0.3, 1.9, 0.00050794}, {0.3, 
 2., 0.3}, {0.4, 0., 0.105297}, {0.4, 0.1, 0.0971176}, {0.4, 0.2, 
 0.0879347}, {0.4, 0.3, 0.0775804}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.0658562}, {0.4, 0.5,
  0.0525278}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.0373228}, {0.4, 0.7, 0.0199293}, {0.4, 
 0.8, 0.134195}, {0.4, 0.9, 0.022837}, {0.4, 1., 0.0489554}, {0.4, 
 1.1, 0.0743245}, {0.4, 1.2, 0.0573271}, {0.4, 1.3, 0.0424257}, {0.4,
 1.4, 0.0298448}, {0.4, 1.5, 0.0196724}, {0.4, 1.6, 
 0.0118602}, {0.4, 1.7, 0.00624515}, {0.4, 1.8, 0.00258557}, {0.4, 
 1.9, 0.000599978}, {0.4, 2., 0.4}, {0.5, 0., 0.158919}, {0.5, 0.1, 
 0.150508}, {0.5, 0.2, 0.141066}, {0.5, 0.3, 0.13042}, {0.5, 0.4, 
 0.118364}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.104657}, {0.5, 0.6, 0.0890138}, {0.5, 0.7, 
 0.0711086}, {0.5, 0.8, 0.0505737}, {0.5, 0.9, 0.027009}, {0.5, 1., 
 0.103857}, {0.5, 1.1, 0.0308537}, {0.5, 1.2, 0.0637824}, {0.5, 1.3, 
 0.0471817}, {0.5, 1.4, 0.0331969}, {0.5, 1.5, 0.0218995}, {0.5, 1.6,
  0.0132207}, {0.5, 1.7, 0.00697416}, {0.5, 1.8, 0.00289373}, {0.5, 
1.9, 0.000673157}, {0.5, 2., 0.5}, {0.6, 0., 0.220255}, {0.6, 0.1, 
 0.21202}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.202773}, {0.6, 0.3, 0.192342}, {0.6, 0.4, 
0.180527}, {0.6, 0.5, 0.167089}, {0.6, 0.6, 0.15175}, {0.6, 0.7, 
0.134191}, {0.6, 0.8, 0.114054}, {0.6, 0.9, 0.0909496}, {0.6, 1., 
 0.064481}, {0.6, 1.1, 0.03427}, {0.6, 1.2, 0.0689124}, {0.6, 1.3, 
 0.0385372}, {0.6, 1.4, 0.0358715}, {0.6, 1.5, 0.023682}, {0.6, 1.6, 
 0.0143136}, {0.6, 1.7, 0.00756219}, {0.6, 1.8, 0.00314342}, {0.6, 
  1.9, 0.000732734}, {0.6, 2., 0.4}, {0.7, 0., 0.287881}, {0.7, 0.1, 
  0.280083}, {0.7, 0.2, 0.271313}, {0.7, 0.3, 0.261405}, {0.7, 0.4, 
  0.250165}, {0.7, 0.5, 0.237362}, {0.7, 0.6, 0.222728}, {0.7, 0.7, 
 0.205956}, {0.7, 0.8, 0.186702}, {0.7, 0.9, 0.164596}, {0.7, 1., 
0.139263}, {0.7, 1.1, 0.110354}, {0.7, 1.2, 0.0775874}, {0.7, 1.3, 
 0.0408017}, {0.7, 1.4, 0.0380534}, {0.7, 1.5, 0.0251402}, {0.7, 1.6,
 0.0152104}, {0.7, 1.7, 0.00804645}, {0.7, 1.8, 0.00334982}, {0.7, 
 1.9, 0.000782178}, {0.7, 2., 0.3}, {0.8, 0., 0.360601}, {0.8, 0.1, 
 0.353393}, {0.8, 0.2, 0.345259}, {0.8, 0.3, 0.336038}, {0.8, 0.4, 
 0.325544}, {0.8, 0.5, 0.313552}, {0.8, 0.6, 0.299803}, {0.8, 0.7, 
 0.283998}, {0.8, 0.8, 0.265805}, {0.8, 0.9, 0.244867}, {0.8, 1., 
  0.220822}, {0.8, 1.1, 0.193336}, {0.8, 1.2, 0.162146}, {0.8, 1.3, 
  0.127104}, {0.8, 1.4, 0.0882261}, {0.8, 1.5, 0.0457207}, {0.8, 1.6, 
 0.0159595}, {0.8, 1.7, 0.00845212}, {0.8, 1.8, 0.00352328}, {0.8, 
  1.9, 0.00082387}, {0.8, 2., 0.2}, {0.9, 0., 0.437446}, {0.9, 0.1, 
 0.430904}, {0.9, 0.2, 0.423481}, {0.9, 0.3, 0.415021}, {0.9, 0.4, 
  0.40534}, {0.9, 0.5, 0.39422}, {0.9, 0.6, 0.381406}, {0.9, 0.7, 
  0.366606}, {0.9, 0.8, 0.349494}, {0.9, 0.9, 0.329717}, {0.9, 1., 
  0.30692}, {0.9, 1.1, 0.280773}, {0.9, 1.2, 0.251014}, {0.9, 1.3, 
   0.217496}, {0.9, 1.4, 0.180224}, {0.9, 1.5, 0.139385}, {0.9, 1.6, 
 0.0953512}, {0.9, 1.7, 0.0486627}, {0.9, 1.8, 0.0036711}, {0.9, 1.9,
  0.000859502}, {0.9, 2., 0.1}, {1., 0., 0.517638}, {1., 0.1, 
  0.511792}, {1., 0.2, 0.505102}, {1., 0.3, 0.497419}, {1., 0.4, 
   0.488558}, {1., 0.5, 0.478307}, {1., 0.6, 0.466412}, {1., 0.7, 
   0.452583}, {1., 0.8, 0.436497}, {1., 0.9, 0.417802}, {1., 1., 
  0.396143}, {1., 1.1, 0.371189}, {1., 1.2, 0.342673}, {1., 1.3, 
  0.310437}, {1., 1.4, 0.274472}, {1., 1.5, 0.234941}, {1., 1.6, 
  0.192177}, {1., 1.7, 0.146665}, {1., 1.8, 0.0990051}, {1., 1.9, 
  0.0498752}, {1., 2., 1.}}
```

I have used of ListPlot3D to plot data.

I obtained the bellow figure:
[image]

How can I smooth the edges (some of which are highlighted with yellow) in such a way that be not sharp; and the final plot be a good-looking figure.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting `InterpolationOrder`? (Don't set it too high, tho.)

Comment: No it isn't helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this way:

```
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: OP claims it wasn't helpful…

Comment: @Guess who it is, It is really not helpful if used like this `ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3]`. I am not sure why.

Comment: Yes I had used the ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3] it was not helpful.

Comment: @Algohi, is it possible send complete commands for producing the plot (I mean options for its color and something else.

Comment: @Ackaran, this is the default them in V10.